# How to configure JNDI properties file in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, jndi, messagebroker

I am trying to run a JMX test to publish JMS messages to ActiveMQ broker from JMeter. If I check the option to use jndi.properties file as below, it does not specifically ask for the path of the file.  I want to know how to configure a JNDI properties file in JMeter. Is there a specific place to add the JNDI properties file or how can I provide the path to it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JMS Publisher documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher)

> use **jndi.properties**. Note that the file must be on the classpath - e.g. by updating the **user.classpath** JMeter property

So if you put the *jndi.properties* file somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) JMeter will pick it up.

Another option is setting **user.classpath** property and include *jndi.properties* file location there, it can be done in 2 ways:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   user.classpath=/path/to/your/jndi.properties
   ```
2. Pass the property value via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Juser.classpath=/path/to/your/jndi.properties -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on fine tuning your JMeter instance(s) via setting and overriding properties.